# Add Preloader which is horizontally spinning

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm currently working on a preloader, which should spin an image horizontally.

I found various threads and ideas, all containing basicaly of something like that:

```
 <style>
      .imageRotateHorizontal{
    -moz-animation: spinHorizontal 3s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: spinHorizontal 3s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spinHorizontal 3s infinite linear;
    animation: spinHorizontal 3s infinite linear;
}


@keyframes spinHorizontal {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(359deg);
  }
}
  </style>
```

My problem is, that the image is like spinning half way through, as you can see in this fiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/1hw3xamj/

So basically, the image turns until mirrored and then turns back...

My goal though, is to have it permanently spinning in one direction, and not turn, when its mirrored...

I hope you get what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The image is rotating the full 360 degrees. Its hard to tell, because the image you are using is symmetrical.

I've changed the image to a different one so you can see that its spinning: https://jsfiddle.net/1hw3xamj/

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/Flat_tick_icon.svg/1200px-Flat_tick_icon.svg.png" class="rotate" width="200" height="200" />
```

Comment: Oh well, you're right... Is there any way to give that thing like more depth, so it's clear, that its spinning around?

Comment: Programmatically I'm not sure. The easiest way I can see would just be to make the image a bit asymmetrical.